# How to call a function in a Reusable component in React

Tags: reactjs

Hi I am working on a React project in my project one button is coming soo many times. So I created one component for Button and I am reusing that component where ever I get a button. Now the problem is when I am trying to apply onClick function to that Button component, my function is not working so please help me to resolve this issue.

This is Button Component Button.js

```
import React from "react";
import "./Button.css";

const Button = () => {
  return (
    <div>
      <button className="btn btn-primary">Show login button</button>
    </div>
  );
};

export default Button;
```

This is Button.css, I have written nothing in this

This is App.js

```
import React, { useState } from "react";
import Button from "./Button/Button";
import "./App.css";

const App = () => {
  const [hideForm, setHideForm] = useState(false);

  const showLoginForm = () => {
    setHideForm(true);
  };
  return (
    <div className="container">
      <div className="row justify-content-center">
        <div className="col-4">
          {hideForm ? (
            <div className="loginform">
              <form>
                <div className="form-group">
                  <label htmlFor="email">Email</label>
                  <input
                    type="email"
                    className="form-control"
                    id="email"
                    placeholder="Enter email"
                  ></input>
                </div>
                <div className="form-group">
                  <label htmlFor="password">Password</label>
                  <input
                    type="password"
                    className="form-control"
                    id="password"
                    placeholder="Enter password"
                  ></input>
                </div>
                <button type="submit" className="btn btn-primary mt-3">
                  Submit
                </button>
              </form>
            </div>
          ) : (
            <div className="signupform">
              <form>
                <div className="form-group">
                  <label htmlFor="firstname">Firstname</label>
                  <input
                    type="text"
                    className="form-control"
                    id="firstname"
                    placeholder="Enter firstname"
                  ></input>
                </div>
                <div className="form-group">
                  <label htmlFor="lastname">Lastname</label>
                  <input
                    type="text"
                    className="form-control"
                    id="lastname"
                    placeholder="Enter lastname"
                  ></input>
                </div>
                <div className="form-group">
                  <label htmlFor="email">Email</label>
                  <input
                    type="email"
                    className="form-control"
                    id="email"
                    placeholder="Enter email"
                  ></input>
                </div>
                <div className="form-group">
                  <label htmlFor="password">Password</label>
                  <input
                    type="password"
                    className="form-control"
                    id="password"
                    placeholder="Enter password"
                  ></input>
                </div>
                <button type="submit" className="btn btn-primary mt-3">
                  Submit
                </button>
              </form>
            </div>
          )}
          <div className="buttons mt-3">
            <Button onClick={() => showLoginForm()}></Button>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
};

export default App;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
const Button = ({handleClick}) => {
    return (
        <div>
            <button onClick={handleClick} className='btn btn-primary'>Show login button</button>
        </div>
    )
}
```

Use It like this:

```
<Button handleClick={()=>anyFunc()}/>
or
<Button handleclick={anyFunc}/>
``
```

Comment: Hi @Mohinder singh I tried your code it is showing this error Error: Too many re-renders. React limits the number of renders to prevent an infinite loop.

Comment: can u Share your code same as mine. Just button component and how you are using it.

Comment: import React from "react";
import "./Button.css";


const Button = ({handleClick}) => {
    return (
        <div>
            <button onClick={handleClick} className='btn btn-primary'>Show login button</button>
        </div>
    )
}

export default Button

Comment: and how you are using it.

Comment: <Button handleclick={ showLoginForm()}></Button>

Comment: that () is the prolem, don't use these in the end.

Comment: maybe name is the problem. U are Using handleclick not handleClick make it same

Answer (score 0):

You can pass the Parent's on click event to child as a props and when you click on the child component's button event that is being declared on the parent's component can be called. Here is how you can do it:

Code on the Parent Component:

```
 const myClick =()=>{
 // on click will be called here when button will be pressed
}
  <Button onClick={this.myClick}></Button>
```

Code on the Child Component:

```
<button onClick={this.props.myClick}>Click Here</button>
```

Comment: It is called automatically and maybe lead to Infinite loop.